# How does Xcode know what symbols are in a project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I was looking at doxygene and I noticed that its output for objective-C is less than optimal, so I was looking at doxygene's internals(in which all syntax analyzers consolidated into a huge blob), and then I decided that it was going to take a lot of work just to figure out where to begin with that.

So I thought, ok let's start by creating a dictionary/tree from an objective-c source file which it seems Xcode does already(because symbols are search able). And it seems to use LLVM"clang" somehow.  Does anyone know how I can invoke "clang" to return a structure of the symbols in a project/document?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't directly use the "clang++" binary for this purpose. The clang++ binary is actually a *very* small wrapper around the Clang C++ libraries. Xcode uses libclang (a C wrapper around the C++ libraries) for its C++ parsing needs.

Thus, to get the information you want, you will need to use libclang. [On this page are the slides and video](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/) of a presentation Doug Gregor (the main developer of Clang) gave at the 2010 dev meeting entitled "libclang: Thinking Beyond the Compiler".

Many people in the clang community have expressed interest in replacing Doxygen's parser with clang. So you are not alone. However, I believe it is not a small project.